# Video not playing in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm not able to play a video in Firefox. Firefox gives a warning on `URL.createObjectURL(video)`:

```
Media resource blob could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005)
Details: auto mozilla::SupportChecker::AddMediaFormatChecker(const mozilla::TrackInfo &)::(anonymous class)::operator()() const: Decoder may not have the capability to handle the requested video format with YUV444 chroma subsampling.
```

I also tried the video converter package [convert-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-video) but the same issue occurred.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox won't support that video's format, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1368063.

The suggested solution is to create the video using ffmpeg's `-pix_fmt yuv420p` switch.

Comment: Video formate is H264 High (4:4:4) Profile not working firefox to play?